# Vaadin 7 - retrieve Beanitem from Grid Editor CommitEvent

Tags: grid, editor, vaadin

I am (still) working with Vaadin 7.6.4 and im trying to write my own custom `FieldGroup.CommitHandler`

I am trying to retrieve the currently added item (grid row) from the the commitEvent itself.

While debugging I can see that all the Data is available in a property called `itemId` if I use the following trainwreck: `commitEvent.getFieldBinder().getItemDataSource()` inside the Debug-Inspector, however it is private.
The `itemId` is the exact bean-entity i want to access. I only managed to access single fields of the entity with the following trainwreck: `commitEvent.getFieldBinder().getField(propertyId).getValue()`. However this is cumbersome and does not give me the entity as a whole (and to be precise does not retrieve the information from the entity, but rather from the displaying elements of the grid).

Is there a way to access the currently edited entity (which is the datasource for the edited grid row), without declaring the entire grid as a global field and call the `grid.getSelected()`-method?

Also, is there a data-wise difference between post- and preCommit?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are apparently using BeanItemContainer based on your comment of `itemId`, You could try something like the following:

```
BeanItem item = (BeanItem) commitEvent.getFieldBinder().getItemDataSource();
MyBean bean = (MyBean) item.getBean();
```

getBean() in this case returns `itemId`.

Comment: unfortunately, an exception get called in my line `BeanItem item = (BeanItem) commitEvent.getFieldBinder().getItemDataSource();` - seems like "Item" cannot be casted to "BeanItem"